# How to add a simple DSL to a Ruby class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I implement a class that lets me register other classes with a DSL and can access them once instantiated like the example below:

```
module Google
  class Search
    def self.run 
      puts :search
    end
  end

  class Map
    def self.run 
      puts :map
    end
  end

  class Calendar
    def self.run 
      puts :calendar
    end
  end
end

class One
  has Google::Search
  has Google::Map

  def perform
    # run through all registered classes, instantiate and then call run on each
  end
end

class Two
  has Google::Calendar

  def perform
    # run through all registered classes, instantiate and then call run on each
  end
end

One.new.peform 
# => 'search'
# => 'map'

One.new.peform 
# => 'calendar'
```

Comment: You can implement a DSL as typically a base class or mixin. Do you have a specific target? Have you tried to implement anything? Your code explains the problem well, but it's a bit of an empty shell, so it's not clear how much you know about how you would start to write DSL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your initial code contains several errors, it would not even pass ruby interpreter.

First of all you need to implement DSL handler:

```
module DSLHandler
  @@classes = {}
  def classes
    @@classes[self.name] ||= []
  end
  def has clazz
    classes << clazz
    puts "registered #{clazz} in #{classes}"
  end
  extend self
end
```

Now there is a need to understand, that since `has` is invoked on class level, perform *must* be invoked on the same level. The summing up:

```
class Google ; end

class Google::Search
  def self.run
    puts :search
  end
end

class Google::Map
  def self.run
    puts :map
  end
end

class Google
  extend DSLHandler

  has Google::Search
  has Google::Map

  def self.perform
    classes.each { |clazz| clazz.run }
  end
end

Google.perform
```

The result is as expected:

```
# ⇒ registered Google::Search in [Google::Search]
# ⇒ registered Google::Map in [Google::Search, Google::Map]
# ⇒ search
# ⇒ map
```

Comment: Nested class in ruby is also known as inner class.

Comment: @NielSalter how can I implement it such that a second class can have its own list of contained classes

Comment: @NeilSlater I will never answer SO questions before having my morning coffee again. Repeated 3 times. Updated an answer.

Comment: @NeilSalter. When I test your solution I don't get the expected result. It still isn't handling separate classes. I've updated my question which may help

Comment: @Roman There was an error in hash key implementation. There was `@@classes[self.class.name]` while this code is being run at class level. Hence there should be `@@classes[self.name]` (`self.class` is Class, while `self` is an instance of `Class` class.) I’ve updated an answer, now it works perfectly.

Comment: @mudasobwa yes I just saw your edit. Works like a charm now. Looks like the coffee kicked in :P

Comment: @mudasobwa I would go so far as doing `@@classes[self]` so to handle anonymous classes.